# Probability Theory: On weak convergence of distribution functions.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, weak-convergence

On the top of page 97 in Durrett's text on Probability, it says that a sequence of distribution functions $F_n$ **converges weakly** to some limit function $F$ if it converges to $F$ for all continuity points of $F$.

I am trying to make sense out of Durrett's comment: To see that convergence at continuity points is enough to identify the limit, observe that $F$ is right continuous and by Exercise 1.2.3, the discontinuities of $F$ are at most a countable set.

What is the point of his comment here?  Why is he talking about the set of discontinuities being countable? Why is that relevant? I agree with him that this is true (this is because $F$ is nondecreasing) but who cares?

The only thing I have proven (fairly trivial) is that $F$ must be nondecreasing when restricted to its continuity points. (This follows directly from it being the pointwise limit of nondecreasing functions.)

Can you shed any light on this?

Comment: What is the measure of the countable set of discontinuities?

Comment: The measure of a countable set is 0.  How is that enough to identify the limit? How do I know that $F$ is right continuous?

Comment: What is $F$? I think we need more information before addressing these issues.

Comment: $F$ is the pointwise limit as stated above.

Comment: $F$ is the weak limit of the $F_n$, ok. But, what are the $F_n$? They are functions $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$? Do you know anything more about them than they are functions?

Comment: Please reread the problem and look the relevant information up before attempting to solve it.  I am assuming some basic understanding of probability theory, like knowing what a distribution function is.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11354/discussion-between-user710587-and-tom)

Answer (score 2):

Let it be so that $F,F_{1},F_{2},\ldots$ are distribution functions
and denote $C:=\left\{ x\in\mathbb{R}\mid F\text{ continuous at }x\right\} $.

Assume that $F_{n}\left(x\right)$ converges to $F\left(x\right)$
for any $x\in C$. Then $F\left(x\right)$ is determined for every
$x\in C$. However, what we want is that $F\left(x\right)$ is determined
for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$. For every $x\in\mathbb{R}$ we can find
a sequence $\left(x_{k}\right)$ in $C$ with $x_{k}\geq x$ and $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}x_{k}=x$.
The fact that such a sequence exists is a consequence of the fact
that $\mathbb{R}-C$ is countable. Since $F$ as a distribution function
is right-continuous we now have $F\left(x\right)=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}F\left(x_{k}\right)$.
Here the $F\left(x_{k}\right)$ are determined because $x_{k}\in C$
so automatically the $F\left(x\right)$ is determined. In special
case $x\in C$ you can take $x_{k}=x$ for every $k$.

Comment: drhab, I never said that $F$ was a distribution function. I agree (after proof), that $F$ is decreasing at the points where the limit exists... Can we still prove it is right continuous?

Comment: No. Define $F_{n}$ by $x\mapsto1$ if $x\geq\frac{1}{n}$ and $x\mapsto0$
otherwise and define $F$ by $x\mapsto1$ if $x>0$, $x\mapsto0$
if $x<0$ and $x\mapsto c$ otherwise, where $c$ is allowed to be
any constant you like. Then set $\mathbb{R}-\left\{ 0\right\} $ is
the set of its continuity points and indeed we have $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}F_{n}\left(x\right)=F\left(x\right)$
for $x\in\mathbb{R}-\left\{ 0\right\} $. However, if $c\neq1$ then
$F$ is not right-continuous. One speaks of weak convergence
$F_{n}\rightarrow F$ only if next to the $F_{n}$ also $F$ is a
distribution function.

Comment: In the example of my comment $F_{n}\left(x\right)$ converges for
every $x$ if you take $c=0$. Then $F$ is not a distribution function.