# Convergence of distribution functions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, weak-convergence

I am trying to prove the **equivalence** of the following statements:

(i)  $F_n(z) \to F(z)$ as $n \to \infty$ for all $z$ at which $F$ is continuous.

(ii) $F_n(z) \to F(z)$ as $n \to \infty$ for all $z$ in a dense subset $D$ of $\mathbb{R}$

where $F_n$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$, and $F$ are distributions functions on $\mathbb{R}$.

I have found 2 questions, namely [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/552422/probability-theory-on-weak-convergence-of-distribution-functions) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1079661/a-probability-function-is-determined-on-a-dense-set-where-is-density-used-in-th), which look related to my topic.

One approach mentioned there might come in handy here, I guess.

We introduce $C:=\left\{ x\in\mathbb{R}\mid F\text{ continuous at }x\right\}$.

And if I prove that $C$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ I am done with one direction already. 
I think, one idea to start is to find for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$ a sequence $(x_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ that converges to $x$. I feel that the definition of a dense subset is now somewhere close, but I still cannot catch it.

Any help on the matter would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Actually, since $F(x)$ is a monotonic function, it has at most infinite countable discontinuity set. Hence, the density of $C$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can only be a countable number of atoms (points at which the CDF is not continuous). An atom is a point $x$ where $P(X=x)>0$. And $P(X=x)$ is called the mass of the atom at $x.$

Observe that there cannot be more than $n$ atoms with mass greater than $1/n.$ So the set $\{\mbox{atoms with mass >1/n}\}$ is finite. The set of all atoms is $\bigcup_n\{\mbox{atoms with mass >1/n}\},$ which is a countable union of finite sets and thus countable. Thus the set of non-atoms (continuity pts) has countable complement and is thus dense.

Hint for the other direction: note that a function's values on a dense subset determines its value at each point of continuity.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the other direction please? I have been trying to solve the same problem but I am stuck at this point. I was able to obtain a sequence $\{x_m \} \in D$ where $D$ is a dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$ converging to $x$, a continuity point of $F$ that is not in $D$. Then I have following reults, $F_n(x_m) \to F(x_m)$ for all $m$. And $F(x_m) \to F(x)$. But how do I get to the required result from here? That is, $F_n(x) \to F(x)$. We do not know about the conitnuity of $F_n$.